# Why my angular6 module's name has double path name?

Tags: angular

When I visit my web application.The net recored shows that there is a module named `recommend-recommend-module.ts`.

[image]

Here's my code:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/project/introduction', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'project', loadChildren: './project/project.module#ProjectModule' },
      { path: 'angular', loadChildren: './angular/angular.module#AngularModule' },
      { path: 'recommend', loadChildren: './recommend/recommend.module#RecommendModule' },
      { path: '**', redirectTo: '/project/introduction' },
    ],
  }
];
```

Why the module named `recommend-recommend-module.ts` other than `recommend-module.ts`

Comment: you might have named it that way.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: may be i am not getting your question

Comment: I have added a image.You can see the module.My question is why it's named `recommend-recommend-module.ts`.What should I do if I just wanna name `recommend-module.ts`

Answer (score 0):

You might have created the module via

> ng create module /recommend/recommend

I had this problem once that if you create something and add a path, it will create the name including the folder name if it is at a custom location.

Comment: i see, and now i see the rest of those modules on the screen, isnt it always exactly following "<folder>-<module>.module.ts? you have "project-project..." and "angular-angular...."